# How to replace a string contains quotation marks in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have a CSV file is about HTML code. 
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv 
import seaborn as sns
import re
import os
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",1000000000)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",1000000000)

dirs = os.listdir('DataCollectionCA/')
for i in dirs:
    if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ".csv":
        print(i)

dirss = 'DataCollectionCA/'

print("<div class=\"\"ContentGrid\"\">")

df = pd.read_csv(dirss+"7197409.csv") #導入資料
df_num = len(df) #計算有多少行
print(df_num)
real_df_num = df_num+1
with open ('719740999999.csv', 'a' ,newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['互動作者','發表時間','互動內容'])

for post in range(1,real_df_num):
    with open (dirss+'7197409.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile: 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        column0 = [row[0] for row in reader]
        for i, rows in enumerate(column0):
            if i == post:
                row000 = rows
    with open (dirss+'7197409.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile: 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        column1 = [row[1] for row in reader]
        for j, rows in enumerate(column1):
            if j == post:
                row001 = rows
    with open (dirss+'7197409.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile: 
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        column2 = [row[2] for row in reader]
        for k, rows in enumerate(column2):
            if k == post:
                row002 = rows
    author = row000
    res_time = row001
    original_html_code = row002
    new_html_code_01 = original_html_code.replace('"<div class=""ContentGrid"">', " ")
    new_html_code_02 = new_html_code_01.replace('<br>', " ")
    print(new_html_code_02)
    print("======")
    with open ('719740999999.csv', 'a' ,newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile: 
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([author,res_time,new_html_code_02])
```

I want to use Python to replace the following string (it is HTML code):

```
"<div class=""ContentGrid"">

<img data-icons="":~("" src=""

"" onload=""DrawImage(this)"" width=""300"" height=""617"">
```

and so on.

I tried to use the following code to do it, but it was failed.
I want to replace to blank.

```
new_html_code_02 = re.sub('<div class=\"\"ContentGrid\"\">', " ", new_html_code_01)
new_html_code_02 = re.sub('<div class=""ContentGrid"">', " ", new_html_code_01)
```

The new file still shows these string. I don't know what to solve.

Comment: Can you add a before and after for the string replacement so that we understand better what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to change strings to blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but the second replacement statement you tried worked for me. You don't need to escape the qoutes (`"`). If you only want to replace static expressions, you don't even need to use regex, you could also use Python's `replace()` method of the `string` type:

```
import re


html = '<div class=""ContentGrid"">' \
       '<img data-icons="":~("" src=""' \
       '"" onload=""DrawImage(this)"" width=""300"" height=""617"">'

new_html = re.sub('<div class=""ContentGrid"">', " ", html)
print(new_html)

new_html = html.replace('<div class=""ContentGrid"">', " ")
print(new_html)
```

Comment: It should be  "<div class=""ContentGrid"">, it contains quotation mark

Comment: That one extra `"` doesn't change anything. It will still work.

Comment: I edited the question. I think it is very strange. I copied your code to run it. It is work. However, I use it in my code. It does not work......

Comment: Don't forget to add that extra `"` to the replace string.